# Why the Grid view zooms after JavaScript pop up

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a simple ASP.NET page with a Grid view (pulling data form SQL-DB), a textbox and a save button.

To add info; the user Inputs info into Textbox and press Save Button. When the user clicks on save button, s/he is presented with a JavaScript pop up saying “Saved”

Everything is working perfectly fine; the only problem I am having is; after this JavaScript pop up the Grid view just zooms.

How can I fix it?

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('Saved')</script>");
```

### Zooms

The contact in the Grid view expends in size However goes back to normal after a Page refresh.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say that the gridview "zooms"?

Comment: @JeffreyBlake: The contact in the Grid view expends in size However goes back to normal after a Page refresh.

Comment: @Anjum check your HTML and make sure nothing is broken before the alert. The alert might just be making worse an existing issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one, instead of Response.Write()

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "scriptSave", "alert('Saved');", true);
```